# How to keep the proportions when switching from png to pdf in R

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I inherited from a colleague a function that creates a plot, lets call it `make_plot`

```
make_plot <- function(data) {plot(data)} 
data <- rnorm(12)
```

Assume there are many more things between parenthesis, some of which I'm not even experienced enough to change, but I'm keeping it simple here. The function was initially develop to produce plots in png format, keeping the correct proportion between labels, dots and other elements.

```
png("plot.png",width=500,height=500)
make_plot(data)
dev.off()
```

I'm in the process of publishing a paper that includes plots produced with such function, but the editor of the journal wants of us provide plots in pdf format. Unfortunately, when switching to pdf, even if the proportions between width and height are maintained, some elements change their relative size to others.

```
pdf("plot.pdf",width=5,height=5)
make_plot(data)
dev.off()
```

How can I force R to produce pdf plots with proportions that emulate the png rendition? As I mentioned before, changing the function from within is not an option. You can run the code above to emulate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the png device is given in pixels, the pdf in inches. Using the fact that the (default) resolution is 72 points per inch (ppi) (see `?png`), you get the same proportions for the pdf if you use:

```
pdf("plot.pdf",width=500/72,height=500/72)
```